# Content not going down when drop down menu collapses

Tags: html, css

I´m trying to adjust the content of my pages when the main Menu collapses. What happens is that the links dropped from that Menu stay on top of the content and i would like it to go down also.
I do have some pages from Wordpress integrated in my website that the content goes down but unfortunately i can´t see the code of wordpress to do that.

Here is the HTML:

```
<nav id="navigation">
<a class="menu_button" href="#footer_nav" onclick="toggleNav(); return false;">&#9776;  MENU</a>
<ul id="navigation_list" role="navigation">
    <li><a href="Dicas.html">Dicas</a></li>
    <li><a href="Viagens.html">Viagens</a></li>
    <li><a href="Paises.html">Paises</a></li>
    <li><a href="Comboios.html">Comboios</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost/Interrail/public_html/blog/wordpress/">Blog</a></li>
</ul>
```

The Javascript:

```
<script>
    var originalNavClasses;

    function toggleNav() {
        var elem = document.getElementById('navigation_list');
        var classes = elem.className;
        if (originalNavClasses === undefined) {
            originalNavClasses = classes;
        }
        elem.className = /expanded/.test(classes) ? originalNavClasses : originalNavClasses + ' expanded';
    }
</script>
```

And the CSS:

```
#navigation {
padding: 10px;
background-color: #000;
color: #fff;
text-align: right;}

#navigation ul {
display: none;
list-style: none;
margin-right: 0;
padding-left: 0;
margin-bottom: 0;}

#navigation ul.expanded {
display: block;}

#navigation li a {
display: block;
padding: 10px 0;
border-top: 1px solid #666;
font-size: 1.2em;
color: #ccc;
text-decoration: none;}

.menu_button {
display: block;
text-align: right;
color: #ffc;
text-decoration: none;}

.menu_button:hover {
color: #58cbdb;
text-decoration: none;}
```

Here is my [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/VE7dQ/) LINK

Answer (score 0):

try this http://jsfiddle.net/VE7dQ/4/

```
  $(function () { 
  $('.menu_button').click(function () {
    var originalNavClasses ="";
   var elem = document.getElementById('navigation_list');
    var classes = elem.className;
    if (originalNavClasses === undefined) {
        originalNavClasses = classes;
    }
    elem.className = /expanded/.test(classes) ? originalNavClasses : originalNavClasses + ' expanded';
  });
```

});

Comment: Dear Mahmoude Elghandour thanks for your answer. Unfortunately the content below doesn´t drop. Maybe i didn´t explain my issue better but let´s assume there´s a div below the <ul>. I can the <div> goes down when the Menu drops down?

Comment: I can't get what you really needed but I update the link http://jsfiddle.net/VE7dQ/5/

Comment: Almost there. What i want is not a DIV attached to that menu. Imagine that same div="info" already fixed on the page, not belonging to the drop down menu. When the drop down menu expands, that Div must go down also. What happens in my page currently is that the drop down menu overlaps the Div.

Comment: okay just put the div="info" in any place in the page and it will work with drop down menu